# Trouble with a specific character (") in text file in R

Tags: r, loops, text

In R I have a folder with many pictures. I would like to create one text file where the folder path of all my pictures are written (1 line/picture) as:

data/obj/scan 1.png

data/obj/scan 2.png

But finally I got in my text file:

"data/obj/""scan 1.png"

"data/obj/""scan 2.png"

How to remove or avoid the " ?

Here is my program:

```
folder <- "C:/Users/user/Desktop/R/test/"

jpeg <- list.files(folder) 

train <- matrix(nrow=as.numeric(length(jpeg)),ncol=2)

ind <- 0

for (k in jpeg){
  ind <- ind +1

  name <- paste0(k)
  train[ind,1:2] <- cbind(as.character("data/obj/"),as.character(name))

}

write.table(train, "train.txt", sep="", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks but still have " in the text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

You'll need to provide `quote = FALSE` to `write.table` to avoid writing the quotation marks:

```
folder <- "C:/Users/user/Desktop/R/test/"

jpeg  <- basename(list.files(folder, pattern= "\\.jpeg$", recursive = TRUE))
train <- paste0("data/obj/", jpeg)

write.table(train, "train.txt", sep="", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```